# What's a reasonable way to read an entire text file as a single string?

Tags: ruby, string, file, io

I am sure this is an easy one; I just couldn't find the answer *immediately* from Google.

I know I could do this (right?):

```
text = ""
File.open(path).each_line do |line|
    text += line
end

# Do something with text
```

But that seems a bit excessive, doesn't it? Or is that the way one would do it in Ruby?

Comment: Caveat: Reading the file into memory, AKA slurping, has scalability issues. Ruby, along with Perl and other languages, can read a file line by line almost as fast as it can reading then splitting and looping through it.

Comment: @the Tin Man: That's good advice, and I thank you for it. This question was asked a while ago, so I could be remembering it incorrectly; but I believe my intention at the time was to do some multi-line regex matching on the text of the file, so I did need the whole thing in memory (i.e., I wasn't just planning on reading it line-by-line).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What about [`IO.read()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000883)?

Edit: `IO.read()`, as an added bonus, closes the file for you.

Comment: Does this put the entire file into memory, or does it keep a file pointer so it doesn't use all of your RAM reading a huge file?

Answer (score 200):

[IO.read()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-read) is what you're looking for.
[File](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html) is a subclass of [IO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html), so you may as well just use:

```
text = File.read(path)
```

Can't get more intuitive than that.

Comment: Like my question for s.m., does IO, or File read the whole file into memory, or does it use a file pointer with SEEK to keep track of that instead of loading a big file into memory?

Comment: @Pred it loads it into a string and therefore into memory.

Answer (score 0):

First result I found when searching.

I wanted to change the mode, which doesn't seem possible with `IO.read`, unless I'm wrong?

Anyway, you can do this:

```rb
data = File.open(path,'rb',&:read)
```

It's also good for when you want to use any of the other options:

https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-new