# How to read a large file into a string

Tags: ruby, serialization, io

I'm trying to save and load the states of Matrices (using [`Matrix`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html)) during the execution of my program with the functions `dump` and `load` from [`Marshal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Marshal.html). I can serialize the matrix and get a ~275 KB file, but when I try to load it back as a string to deserialize it into an object, Ruby gives me only the beginning of it.

```
# when I want to save
mat_dump = Marshal.dump(@mat)  # serialize object - OK
File.open('mat_save', 'w') {|f| f.write(mat_dump)}  # write String to file - OK

# somewhere else in the code
mat_dump = File.read('mat_save')  # read String from file - only reads like 5%
@mat = Marshal.load(mat_dump)  # deserialize object - "ArgumentError: marshal data too short"
```

I tried to change the arguments for `load` but didn't find anything yet that doesn't cause an error.

How can I load the entire file into memory? If I could read the file chunk by chunk, then loop to store it in the String and then deserialize, it would work too. The file has basically one big line so I can't even say I'll read it line by line, the problem stays the same.

I saw some questions about the topic:

- "[Ruby serialize array and deserialize back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460423/ruby-serialize-array-and-deserialize-back)"
- "[What's a reasonable way to read an entire text file as a single string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472232/whats-a-reasonable-way-to-read-an-entire-text-file-as-a-single-string)"
- "[How to read whole file in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328495/how-to-read-whole-file-in-ruby)"

but none of them seem to have the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you read it in binary mode?  Maybe the contains strange binary data that stops the file reading (EOF). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130948/ruby-convert-file-to-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marshal` is a binary format, so you need to read and write in binary mode. The easiest way is to use `IO.binread/write`.

```
...
IO.binwrite('mat_save', mat_dump)
...
mat_dump = IO.binread('mat_save')
@mat = Marshal.load(mat_dump)
```

Remember that Marshaling is Ruby version dependent. It's only [compatible under specific circumstances](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Marshal.html) with other Ruby versions. So keep that in mind:

> In normal use, marshaling can only load data written with the same major version number and an equal or lower minor version number.